# getting usb 2.0 running in virtualbox 4.3

Tags: usb-drive

Have version 4.3.10 of virtualbox installed, but i cant find the extention pack for this version, is it avalable?  if not what can i do to get usb 2.0 up and running?  am in desperate need of this being done.  everytime i try to enable it it gives me a message that the extension pack need to be instaled

Answer (score 4):

The VirtualBox Version & Extension can be downloaded from the same place at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

The Extension shows as **VirtualBox 4.3.16 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack** where **4.3.16** is simply the latest version.

There are 2 ways to install it, you either Open VirtualBox and it will tell you that it is missing the Extension, followed by an option to download it. Another is downloading the Extension  from the link provided, opening VirtualBox, going to the main menu and selecting **File - Preferences**. You can also press after opening VirtualBox <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]

From there go to Extension and simply click on the Add button, find the downloaded extension file which corresponds to the VirtualBox version you are using and add it.

[image]

Note that BEFORE adding the extension I recommend adding your user to the `vboxusers` group which is created after installing VirtualBox.

`sudo usermod -aG vboxusers USERNAME`

Adding yourself to the `vboxusers` in combination with the VirtualBox Extension will give you full USB support.

[image]

Comment: problem is according to the vituralbox that is installed it is version 4.3.10 and there id no extension with this ver # and when i tried to use the extension for ver 4.3.16 it gave me an error

Comment: You can then upgrade the current one you have to the latest by simply downloading the latest virtualbox.  Then folllow up with the correct installation. Remember that you can NOT use an extension with any other virtualbox version than the one it mentions.  The 4.3.16 will only work with the same one.

Comment: @CharlesHockenberry and Luis: Old extension packs for 4.3.x are here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3

Comment: Thanks.  Was looking for that link but through the cellphone is very hard ^^